React state update behavng unexpected | React hooks
I created a custom react hook for processing few logs and other data. but i am seeing very weired issue with the state.
// customHook.ts

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useDeployments } from '../../../hooks/query'
import { usePipelineLogParser } from '../../../hooks'

import { pipelineStages } from '../../../constants'

function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

export default function usePipelineStage() {
    const [pipelineStatus, setPipelineStatus] = useState<string>('FAILED')
    const [pipelineLogs, setPipelineLogs] = useState<any>({})
    const [pipelineSteps, setPipelineSteps] = useState<any>([])

    const { groupLogs, makeLogItemStructure } = usePipelineLogParser()
    const { useGetDeploymentLogs } = useDeployments()
    const deploymentLogSvc = useGetDeploymentLogs()

    const loadStageData = async () => {
        // set initial data
        setPipelineSteps(pipelineStages)
        setPipelineLogs(makeLogItemStructure(pipelineStages))

        // pull data from APIs
        await getPipelineStatus()
        const lastDeploymentStatus = await getLastDeployment()

        const logFetchParams = {
            DeploymentId: lastDeploymentStatus.Id,
        }

        await getDeploymentLogs(logFetchParams)
        if (pipelineStatus === 'ACTIVE') {
            getDeploymentLogs(logFetchParams).then()
        }
    }

    const getPipelineStatus = async () => {
        setPipelineStatus('ACTIVE')
        return 'ACTIVE'
    }

    const getLastDeployment = async () => {
        return { Id: '9fc0bffd-f8de-4a0f-b1ea-28396212405e' }
    }

    const getDeploymentLogs = async (logArgs: any) => {
        try {
            await sleep(3000)
            let accumulatedLogs = { ...pipelineLogs } // Initialize with current state
            console.log('Initial data:', accumulatedLogs, pipelineStatus)

            const logs = await deploymentLogSvc.mutateAsync(logArgs)
        } catch (e) {
            setPipelineStatus('FAILED')
            console.error(e)
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        loadStageData().then()
    }, [])

    return { pipelineStatus, pipelineLogs, pipelineSteps }
}

import { usePipelineStage } from '../hooks';

export default function PipelineStage() {
    const { pipelineStatus } = usePipelineStage()
    return (
       <div> {pipelineStatus} </div>
    )
}

The response i am getting from customHook.ts is different from the expected value
Initial data: {} FAILED

I am expecting Initial data: {} FAILED this log to be Initial data: {TEstDAta: {...}} SUCCESS because this console.log is runnig after the state update.
Please ignore the linenumbers on the logs. The shared code is stipped down version. SOmbody explain me the reason for this behavior?

Calling setPipelineStatus does not (and can not) change the value in the local const pipelineStatus. That contains a snapshot of what the state was at the time of this specific render and will never change. Calling setPipelineStatus just asks react to rerender the component. When that new render happens a new local const will be created with the new value, but code from your old render has no access to that.

make sense. i Have updated my question, could you please suggest what could be the issue in this case

Same thing:  pipelineStatus is a const which contains the string 'FAILED', so that's what it logs. Calling setPipelineStatus does not and can not change the value in a local const.  It looks like you already have some code that determines whether it's a success or not; can you have that code return a value telling you that it was a success, and then log that? Eg, const newStatus = await getPipelineStatus(); console.log(newStatus)

ok. I think i had some misunderstanding about state, my expectation was pipelineStatus will be auto-updated by calling setPipelineStatus.
so what should be the approach here? I want to use pipelineStatus in both js and HTML part of the react component.

The HTML part is trivial: when the new render happens, you will render using the new state. As for using it in the JS, if you want to run code on render #1, but use data that won't exist until render #2, you can only do that via code that you write. You already have a getPipelineStatus function to calculate the new status, and a makeLogItemStructure function to calculate the new logs. Save the results of those functions in local variables, and then use those variables instead of the stale state variables.
